# Counting unique words in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, counter

I am having some difficulties with the following data (from a pandas dataframe):

```
Text
0   Selected moments from Fifa game t...
1   What I learned is that I am ...
3   Bill Gates kept telling us it was comi...
5   scenario created a month before the...
... ...
1899    Events for May 19 – October 7 - October CTOvision.com
1900    Office of Event Services and Campus Center Ope...
1901    How the CARES Act May Affect Gift Planning in ...
1902    City of Rohnert Park: Home
1903    iHeartMedia, Inc.
```

I would need to extract the count of unique words per row (after removing punctuation). So, for example:

```
Unique
0   6
1   6
3   8
5   6
... ...
1899    8
1900    8
1901    9 
1902    5
1903    2
```

I tried to do it as follows:

```
df["Unique"]=df['Text'].str.lower()
df["Unique"]==Counter(word_tokenize('\n'.join( file["Unique"])))
```

but I have not got any count, only a list of words (without their frequency in that row).

Can you please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove all Punctuation if you dont need it counted. Leverage sets. `str.split.map(set)` will give you a set. Count the elements in the set there after. Sets do not take multiple unique elements.

**Chained**

```
df['Text'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '').str.split().map(set).str.len()
```

**Stepwise**

```
df[Text]=df['Text'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '')
df['New Text']=df.Text.str.split().map(set).str.len()
```

Comment: This counts punctuation including the hyphen

Comment: @David Erickson, strip them

Comment: `strip` only removes extra spaces not punctuation.

Comment: @David Erickson ` df[Text]=df['Text'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '')`

Comment: I couldn't figure out the regex for extract, so I deleted my answer.

Comment: by the way, I think this is a good answer, so don't get me wrong. I think extract is a little bit cleaner, so I would be curious to see if someone knew how to do that. Extract might not be good for this type of problem because of the punctuation and digits in the middle of sentences, so it's probably better to just replace them. I didn't see anything about extract for this problem on the internets.

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm just updating this as per the comments. This solution accounts for punctuation as well.

```
df['Unique'] =  df['Text'].apply(lambda x: x.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).strip()).str.split(' ').apply(len)
```

Comment: This counts punctuation including the hyphen and is almost the same as wwnde's answer.

Comment: Yes, its essentially the same. His answer wasn't posted when I saw the question. Let me just extend this by accounting for punctuation.

Comment: Either solution works. Although wwnde's is neater in my opinion.

Comment: nice one with the `string` library

Comment: @annicheez, your answer is also very good and I am sorry to have to mark just one. But I gave you previously my vote as well, as it is very good and helpful. I really appreciated your help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @The_Ark glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from collections import Counter

dict = {'A': {0:'John', 1:'Bob'},
        'Desc': {0:'Bill ,Gates Started Microsoft at 18 Bill', 1:'Bill Gates, Again .Bill Gates  and Larry Ellison'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
df['Desc']=df['Desc'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '')
print(df.loc[:,"Desc"])
 
print(Counter(" ".join(df.loc[0:0,"Desc"]).split(" ")).items())
print(len(Counter(" ".join(df.loc[0:0,"Desc"]).split(" ")).items()))
```